# Does Hisoka die in the 2011 anime or in the manga?

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

Before I finished *Hunter x Hunter*, I heard that Hisoka died, but when I finished the anime he hadn't died, so I'm a little confused about it. I'm asking this question on here because google won't give me the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He did die but he came back to life.

The specifics to this ability are not yet elaborated but in **Chapter 357**, it was shown that Nen can be 'programmed' or 'used' even after death.

After his fight with Chrollo, he was declared dead. Suddenly, Machi notices Hisoka's aura coming back. It was then revealed that Hisoka 'begged' his Nen Gum (this is what he called his Nen, or at least in the VIZ translations) to bring him back to life after his death, which it did.